# SQL ALTER TABLE MATHS QUERY

Tags: oracle

I'm trying to use a Maths query ( with a Boolean ) to populate a column in my Oracle SQL Table, but am getting an error 'invalid data type', I've set them up as decimals. Would appreciate any help...  Thanks Gavin

```
ALTER TABLE GS_MRC_EXISTING
ADD IF ( GROSS_LAST + DISC_LAST ) < ( GROSS_THIS + DISC_THIS ) = TRUE THEN DEC_GROSS = ( GROSS_THIS - GROSS_LAST ) 

CREATE TABLE GS_MRC_EXISTING (
CUST_CODE varchar (255),
GROSS_LAST decimal (6,2),
DISC_LAST decimal (6,2),
GROSS_THIS decimal (6,2),
DISC_THIS decimal (6,2),
INC_GROSS decimal (6,2),
INC_DISC decimal (6,2),
DEC_GROSS decimal (6,2),
DEC_DISC decimal (6,2)
)
```

Comment: There is no such things as `ADD IF` in Oracle. Where in the Manual did you find that? Also Oracle has no boolean data type, so the condition ` = TRUE` is also invalid.

Comment: Hi Bob, I just included that so you could see the Data types I'd created, in case that was the issue.   I've managed to populate CUST_CODE, GROSS_LAST, DISC_LAST, GROSS_THIS, DISC_THIS. And need to compare them in order to populate the last four columns.

Answer (score 1):

I'm really not entirely sure of your intent, but perhaps you're attempting to define a computed column:

```
CREATE TABLE GS_MRC_EXISTING (
CUST_CODE varchar (255),
GROSS_LAST decimal (6,2),
DISC_LAST decimal (6,2),
GROSS_THIS decimal (6,2),
DISC_THIS decimal (6,2),
INC_GROSS decimal (6,2),
INC_DISC decimal (6,2),
DEC_GROSS decimal (6,2)
  GENERATED ALWAYS AS (CASE
                         WHEN (GROSS_LAST + DISC_LAST) < (GROSS_THIS + DISC_THIS)
                           THEN GROSS_THIS - GROSS_LAST
                         ELSE 0
                       END),
DEC_DISC decimal (6,2)
)
```

Comment: thanks Bob, I'm trying to add calculate columns based on the value of the other columns. Will creating them in the 'Create Table' section like that work ?